# Good suffix shift table

Tags: algorithm, shift

How do I calculate the good suffix shift for a needle?
I can't seem to understand this answer below..
The needle is skjeskj

```
 goodshift[0] :        !j    1
 goodshift[1] :       !kj    7
 goodshift[2] :      !skj    7
 goodshift[3] :     !eskj    4
 goodshift[4] :    !jeskj    4
 goodshift[5] :   !kjeskj    4
 goodshift[6] :  !skjeskj    4
```

Could anyone explain this?

edit: downvotes? really, stackoverflow?? really????

Comment: You should clarify your question. What is a "good suffix shift"? What is a needle? Where did you get the "answer" in your question - is there any chance it's incorrect?

Comment: @John NG, having the exact same difficulties understanding the good suffix shift table. (INF2220) Please let me know if you figure it out!

Comment: I figured it out, atlast.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how to understand this?

Answer (score 0):

the first character is always 1 ! note that

skjeskj    (length = 7)

j = jump 1;

(k)j = 7  ! we check here, is j without k in the string ? NO, then we jump 7.    (length of needle)

(s)kj = 7 ! we check here, is kj without s in the string ? NO, then we jump 7.

(e)skj = 4 ! we check here, is skj without e in the string ? Yes, then we count from right to left. j(1),k(2),s(3),e(4). Than we found the substring skj without e.

(j)eskj = 4 ! same process, but here the string start with skj than all the substring contains skj have to jump 4 indexes.

(k)jeskj = 4 ! same process.

(s)kjeskj = 4 ! same process.

Hope it's help.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! However, there are a few things I'm curious about. When we pose the question "is X without STR in the string"? I'm confused as to how you determine that. I get that kj is NOT without 's' in the string since we have "SKJeSKJ", so "KJ" is ALWAYS preceded by S. But for "is 'eskj' without j in the string?" I don't get why the answer is YES. The only time we have "eskj" in the string, it IS preceded by J. Any clarifications are highly appreciated.

Comment: i think you misunderstood me, you must always check the substring without the first character of the substring. Exp (e)skj, here you have to check for the skj without e in the needle, and here the skj without e is in the string.